# How to inflate this card correctly?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to view this card in the page but it doesn't show any thing.
I am using firebase as my backend
I tried to inflate the data retrieved from firebase in a table and it worked fine with the append() function but when trying to use cardView it doesn't work
 this is my code:

index.html:

```
  <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
   <span class="mdl-layout-title">Title</span>
    <nav class="mdl-navigation">
     <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
     <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
    </nav>
   </div>
   <main class="mdl-layout__content">
     <div class="page-content"> 
        <!-- Your content goes here -->
                     <div id="comments" class="inline-grid">
                     </div>
      </div>
     </main>
```

and this is my index.js:

```
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("Stories");
rootRef.on("child_added", snap =>{
var title = snap.child("title").val();
var content = snap.child("content").val();
$("#comments").append(" <div class="mdl-card__title">
<h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">"+ title +"</h2>
 </div>
 <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
     "+ content +"
  </div>
   <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
    <a class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-
   effect">
     Get Started
    </a>
   </div>
   <div class="mdl-card__menu">
    <button class="mdl-button mdl-button--icon mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-
     effect">
     <i class="material-icons">share</i>
    </button>
   </div>");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `.append()` the HTML you pass as parameter is not a valid string. When specifying the class attributes you use double quotes which JavaScript interprets as the end of the string because you used double quotes for enclosing the string too.

One fix for this would be escaping the double quotes inside a string using a backslash like so:
`"\""`.

Another way would be to enclose the string in single quotes instead of double quotes. Then you could write something like:

```
var html = '<div class="mdl-card__title">'+
        '<h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">'+ title +'</h2>'+
      '</div>'+
      '<div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">'+ content +'</div>'+
      '<div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">'+
        '<a class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">Get Started</a>'+
      '</div>'+
      '<div class="mdl-card__menu">'+
        '<button class="mdl-button mdl-button--icon mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">'+
            '<i class="material-icons">share</i>'+
        '</button>'+
      '</div>';

$("#comments").append(html);
```

It is not necessary to break the string into so many lines, but I prefer it this way in order to make the HTML more readable.